# Yesod Applicative Forms

Tags: haskell, yesod

I've been playing around with Yesod a bit, and a question arose: how are forms used as Applicatives?

Take:

```
    personForm :: Html -> MForm Synopsis Synopsis (FormResult Person, Widget)
personForm = renderDivs $ Person
    <$> areq textField "Name" Nothing
    <*> areq (jqueryDayField def
        { jdsChangeYear = True -- give a year dropdown
        , jdsYearRange = "1900:-5" -- 1900 till five years ago
        }) "Birthday" Nothing
    <*> aopt textField "Favorite color" Nothing
    <*> areq emailField "Email address" Nothing
    <*> aopt urlField "Website" Nothing
```

I don't understand how the `<*>` operator, which as I understood it takes something of type `f (a -> b)` (i.e. a functor containing a binary function) as its first argument, is being applied to `AForm` values:

```
(AForm f) <*> (AForm g) = AForm $ \mr env ints -> do ...
```

What's going on here?

https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/bf293e6a1f6e691281520d254f72b9441cc64704/yesod-form/Yesod/Form/Types.hs#L95

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It helps here if you try to ignore the detailed types a bit and look at the big picture.

Think of `<$>` and `<*>` as special versions of `$` that work on a different level.

### Applicative Functors in general

Let's look in general first - suppose I had an applicative functor `AF`, and objects

```
x :: AF a
y :: AF b
z :: AF c
```

sort of meaning they "do something" then return values of types `a`, `b` and `c`, and also a pure function

```
f :: a -> b -> c -> d
```

that I wanted to use to combine those values together to get a `d`. Then

```
f <$> x <*> y <*> z    :: AF d
```

works by "doing" `x`, then `y` then `z`, and applying `f` to the result.

Notice that that's similar to `f $ a $ b $ c`.

If your applicative functor agrees with a monad instance, `f <$> x <*> y <*> z` is a nice way of writing

```
do
  a <- x
  b <- y
  c <- z
  return (f a b c)
```

### Forms as applicative functors

Think of a form as something that produces data (from the user). `areq` and `aopt` both return an `AForm sub master ??`. You can ignore the `sub` and `master` - they're for keeping track of site/subsite using the type system. The `??` is the type of data that's returned.

So
`areq textField "Name" Nothing` is a small form that produces `Text`,
`areq (jqueryDayField def) "Birthday" Nothing` is a small form that produces a `Day`,
and the other three also produce `Text`.

Now we have

```
data Person = Person Text Day Text Text Text
```

so that `Person` is a function `:: Text -> Day -> Text -> Text -> Text -> Person`, so if you have

```
Person
    <$> areq textField "Name" Nothing
    <*> areq (jqueryDayField def
        { jdsChangeYear = True -- give a year dropdown
        , jdsYearRange = "1900:-5" -- 1900 till five years ago
        }) "Birthday" Nothing
    <*> aopt textField "Favorite color" Nothing
    <*> areq emailField "Email address" Nothing
    <*> aopt urlField "Website" Nothing
```

you've combined all those forms into one form that produces a single `Person` value, by getting all the individual values of the fields and applying the pure `Person` function to them.

To write that in monadic style you'd write

```
do
    name    <- areq textField "Name" Nothing
    day     <- areq (jqueryDayField def
              { jdsChangeYear = True -- give a year dropdown
              , jdsYearRange = "1900:-5" -- 1900 till five years ago
              }) "Birthday" Nothing
    color   <- aopt textField "Favorite color" Nothing
    email   <- areq emailField "Email address" Nothing
    website <- aopt urlField "Website" Nothing

    return $ Person name day color email website
```

I very much prefer the applicative functor style, because it feels like applying a function to some data instead of performing a sequence of instructions.

### So what's the deal with `<$>` versus `<*>`?

You may have noticed I always do

```
pureFunction <$> af1 <*> af2 <*> af3 <*> af4 ....
```

with `<$>` first, and `<*>` for the rest. That's because the first thing, `pureFunction` is pure and doesn't work on an applicative functor value. It lifts it. (All applicative functors are functors.) Let's compare the types:

```
<$> :: Functor f     =>    (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
<*> :: Applicative f =>  f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

which means that `<$>` is for lifting a pure function, but when you're using `<*>` the left hand side has to already be producing functions instead of just data, which initially seems weird, but not if you use `<$>` first. For example, if you partially apply `(++)` to `"Hello"` you get a function `:: String -> String`, so

```
         getLine             :: IO String             -- produces a String
(++) <$> getLine             :: IO (String -> String) -- produces an appender
(++) <$> getLine <*> getLine ::            IO String  -- produces a combined String
```

Compare that with

```
areq textField "Name" Nothing
   :: AForm sub master Text
```

Since `Person :: Text ->  Day -> Text -> Text -> Text -> Person`, if we give it a `name::Text` value, we get a partially applied function `Person name` of type `Day -> Text -> Text -> Text -> Person`

```
Person <$> areq textField "Name" Nothing
   :: AForm sub master (Day -> Text -> Text -> Text -> Person)
```

which we can than combine using `<*>` with something that produces a `Day` to give something that produces a `(Text -> Text -> Text -> Person)`, and so on until we get something that produces a `Person`. (It all works because `->` associates to the right and `<$>` and `<*>` associate to the left, like `$` does.)

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense now.